# 4-Bit Adder in C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to design a 4-bit adder in C++. I know my issue here lies with me trying to write to a global variable in the full adder function. Is there a way I can write to The carry variable?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool inputs[8] = {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1};
bool answer[4];
bool carry;

short fullAdder(bool val1, bool val2) {
    short sum = 0;
    sum = val1 + val2 + carry;

    switch (sum) {
    case 0:
        carry = 0;
        return 0;
        break;
    case 1:
        carry = 0;
        return 1;
        break;
    case 2:
        carry = 1;
        return 0;
    case 3:
        carry = 1;
        return 1;
        break;
    default: return 0;
    }
}

void rippleAdder() {
    answer[3] = fullAdder(inputs[3], inputs[7]);
    answer[2] = fullAdder(inputs[2], inputs[6]);
    answer[1] = fullAdder(inputs[1], inputs[5]);
    answer[0] = fullAdder(inputs[0], inputs[4]);
    cout << answer[0] << answer[1] << answer[2] << answer[3] << endl;
}

int main() {
    rippleAdder();
}
```

Comment: Your functions' parameter names (`carry`) & your `sum` short are going to be conflicting with your global values.

Comment: If you want to write to the global variable named `carry`, the easiest way would be to not give it a parameter of the same name. Either name it something else, or don't pass it at all.

Comment: I don't get it. If you want to create a hand made adder, you should not be allowed to use the addition... First line of actual *code that do something*: an addition ‍♂️ BTW: it's nibble not ripple.

Comment: @Orace a ripple adder is a thing in digital logic... as opposed to a carry-lookahead adder. This is the kind of thing people are assigned in academia to help them gain insight into this stuff before they get dive into hardware description languages like Verilog or VHDL

Comment: This is a really poor quality question and should not be here. The solution is to declare the carry in rippleAdder and to pass it by reference to the fullAdder see this for a similar low level question [Modify a variable passed by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42473544/modify-a-variable-passed-by-reference)

Comment: The C++ way (one of the ways) would be to put the fullAdder in a class and make carry a member variable of that class. Carry would be initialized each time the FullAdder is created. The rippleAdder reuses one FullAdder instance for each of the bits and destroys it after one addition. If the FullAdder is created as local variable (on the stack), this would be compiled to quite efficient code. Overall a member variable acts like storage between function calls, exactly what you need.

Comment: Overall a private member variable acts like internal storage between function calls, exactly what you need. Compared to static variables inside a function, the variable can be reinitialized or several used in parallel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing carry into the function"by value" not "by reference". I think you should just remove carry as a parameter to the fullAdder function if you want it to be a global variable, but you will need to remember to reinitialize it as the first line of rippleAdder. That would look like this:

```
short fullAdder(bool val1, bool val2) { ... }
void rippleAdder() { carry = 0; ... }
```

Alternatively you could pass an additional pointer to the function and assign the new value of carry to that location at the end of fullAdder. That would look like this:

```
short fullAdder(bool val1, bool val2, bool * carry) {
    short sum = 0;
    sum = val1 + val2 + carry;
    short ret = 0;
    switch (sum) {
    case 0:
        *carry = 0;
        ret = 0;
        break;
    case 1:
        *carry = 0;
        ret = 1;
        break;
    case 2:
        *carry = 1;
        ret = 0;
    case 3:
        *carry = 1;
        ret = 1;
        break;
    default: ret = 0;
  }
  
  return ret;
}
```

... and you'd call it like this:

```
sum[3] = fullAdder(inputs[3], inputs[7], &carry);
```

Comment: Wouldn't reinitializing it defeat the purpose?

Comment: You have to give it an initial state in the rippleAdder function unless you _actually_ want it to be stateful between 4-bit additions.

Comment: You pointed the answer of this XY question in your first sentence. The X question being 'how to modify a variable passed as an argument '. Answer being 'pass it by reference '. No need of global variable, just a local variable named `carry` in the `rippleAdder` function. Then passe it by reference to the `fullAdder` function. No need to pass it twice by value and by address...